# Platform.runLater and Task in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, task, javafx

I have been doing some research on this but I am still VERY confused to say the least.

Can anyone give me a concrete example of when to use `Task` and when to use `Platform.runLater(Runnable);`? What exactly is the difference? Is there a golden rule to when to use any of these?

Also correct me if I'm wrong but aren't these two "Objects" a way of creating another thread inside the main thread in a GUI (used for updating the GUI)?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use `Platform.runLater(...)` for quick and simple operations and `Task` for complex and big operations .

- [Use case for `Platform.runLater(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351959/javafx-how-to-set-default-active-control/13352107#13352107)
- [Use case for `Task`: Task Example in Ensemble App](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Concurrency/Task)

Example: Why Can't we use `Platform.runLater(...)` for long calculations (Taken from below reference).

Problem: Background thread which just counts from 0 to 1 million and update progress bar in UI.

***Code using `Platform.runLater(...)`:***

```
final ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        final int counter = i;
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                bar.setProgress(counter / 1000000.0);
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

> This is a hideous hunk of code, a crime against nature (and
>   programming in general). First, you’ll lose brain cells just looking
>   at this double nesting of Runnables. Second, it is going to swamp the
>   event queue with little Runnables — a million of them in fact.
>   Clearly, we needed some API to make it easier to write background
>   workers which then communicate back with the UI.

***Code using Task :***

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {
        static final int max = 1000000;
        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            updateProgress(i, max);
        }
        return null;
    }
};

ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
bar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
new Thread(task).start();
```

> it suffers from none of the flaws exhibited in the previous code

**Reference :** 
[Worker Threading in JavaFX 2.0](http://fxexperience.com/2011/07/worker-threading-in-javafx-2-0/)

Comment: Task Example in Ensemble App link won't work anymore.

Comment: [This is the correct link](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Concurrency/Task) but I can't edit it in because the edit is only 2 characters.

Comment: To say that one for "quick" operations and another for "complex" ones is a bit misleading. The main difference, after all, is that one allows to run code in the JFX GUI thread from somewhere else, and the other one does the exact opposite - allows to run code in the background thread from the GUI thread (adding a bonus of being able to communicate with the GUI thread in the process).

Comment: I want to save an Image of each of the scenes - and this will take time. Will that cause issues when run on a separate thread via Task? I understood that all gui related work needs to happen on the FxApplication thread.

Comment: @Sergey-Tachenov So you use runLater() from a Task thread to update the GUI thread in cases where you want to do more than just update a single property like progress?

Comment: @user1663987, yeah, you could do that in case you don't do it too often. Or (and I like it better) you could use the `updateValue()` method and make the `value` property encapsulate whatever you need to display in the GUI.

Comment: which Task should I use? `javafx.concurrent.Task` or `com.sun.jmx.snmp.tasks.Task`

Comment: You don't need to declare Runnables like this any more. You can use lambda syntax: `() -> { // Code here }`, or () -> `runSingleThing();`. So, the above code would condense a lot and wouldn't look so overwrought. The answer is still perfectly valid though :)

Answer (score 70):

- `Platform.runLater`: If you need to update a GUI component from a non-GUI thread, you can use that to put your update in a queue and it will be handled by the GUI thread as soon as possible.
- `Task` implements the `Worker` interface which is used when you need to run a long task outside the GUI thread (to avoid freezing your application) but still need to interact with the GUI at some stage.

If you are familiar with Swing, the former is equivalent to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and the latter to the concept of `SwingWorker`.

The [javadoc of Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) gives many examples which should clarify how they can be used. You can also refer to [the tutorial on concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm#JFXIP546).

Comment: Thank you Can you give a small example of how to use platform ?  Can you use it outside the gui thread or? And the task examples in the docs are really unclear

Comment: Yes Platform.runLater can be used outside the GUI thread - that's its main purpose. You might find this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) on tasks more informative than the javadoc.

Comment: You use Platform.runLater like this: `Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {updateYourGuiHere();}});`

Comment: how will i be able to use the GUI components then = :S

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: say that a new chat person connects to my chat program. now i want to update the list of my online people how would i update that textarea from another class?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen It is difficult to answer with so little details. I suggest you ask a separate question where you show the code you have and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Re: `"but still need to interact with the GUI at some stage"`, does `at some stage` mean the `Task` can use the JavaFX Application Thread?

Comment: @KevinMeredith The call method of the Task should not be called on the FX thread - but Task provides bridge methods (updateProgress etc.) that run on the FX thread. See the javadoc  & tutorials for more info.

Answer (score 14):

It can now be changed to lambda version

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        try {
            //an event with a button maybe
            System.out.println("button is clicked");
        } catch (IOException | COSVisitorException ex) {
            Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you are handling a GUI event, you are in the GUI thread. Why would you use runLater() then?

Comment: While you're right, Caglar's answer was trying to highlight the use of a lambda expression, not necessarily to give a good coding example. I use `Platform.runLater(() -> progressBar.setProgress(X/Y));`

Answer (score 3):

One reason to use an explicite Platform.runLater() could be that you bound a property in the ui to a service (result) property. So if you update the bound service property, you have to do this via runLater():

In UI thread also known as the JavaFX Application thread:

```
...    
listView.itemsProperty().bind(myListService.resultProperty());
...
```

in Service implementation (background worker):

```
...
Platform.runLater(() -> result.add("Element " + finalI));
...
```