# Easy way to call method in new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, ui-thread

I'm writing small app and now I discovered a problem.
I need to call one(later maybe two) method (this method loads something and returns the result) without lagging in window of app.

I found classes like `Executor` or `Callable`, but I don't understand how to work with those ones.

Can you please post any solution, which helps me?

Thanks for all advices.

**Edit:** The method *MUST* return the result. This result depends on parametrs.
Something like this:

```
public static HtmlPage getPage(String page) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        return webClient.getPage(page);
}
```

This method works about 8-10 seconds. After execute this method, thread can be stopped. But I need to call the methods every 2 minutes.

**Edit:** I edited code with this:

```
public static HtmlPage getPage(final String page) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                loadedPage = webClient.getPage(page);
            } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    try {
        return loadedPage;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

With this code I get error again (even if I put `return null` out of *catch* block).

Comment: [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) and [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) have examples in the javadoc. And [a topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) on the *concurrency* thread in the official tutorial. That's where I start. You should ask a new question if you don't understand  something *specific* in those materials, or if you're stuck having used the information in them.

Comment: I saw the examples, bud I can't achieve what I want.

Comment: I *think* what you're looking for [`ExecutorService.submit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) with a `Callable<HtmlPage>`, so focus on the documentation for those and related classes/methods. `submit()` should return a `Future<HtmlPage>` which will let you do something (like update the UI) when the result is available.

Comment: I'll see on this, thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend looking at the [Java Thread Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

With a Thread, you can pass in an interface type called a `Runnable`. The documentation can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). A runnable is an object that has a `run` method. When you start a thread, it will call whatever code is in the `run` method of this runnable object. For example:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
              // Insert some method call here.
         }
});
```

Now, what this means is when you call `t.start()`, it will run whatever code you need it to without lagging the main thread. This is called an `Asynchronous` method call, which means that it runs in parallel to any other thread you have open, like your `main` thread. :)

Comment: I try something like this, but it didn't work (more info in next answer)

Comment: how to pass argument to the calling method

Answer (score 39):

Since Java 8 you can use shorter form:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    // Insert some method call here.
}).start();
```

**Update:**
Also, you could use method reference:

```
class Example {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Thread(Example::someMethod).start();
    }
    
    public static void someMethod(){
        // Insert some code here
    }
    
}
```

You are able to use it when your argument list is the same as in required [@FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), e.g. [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

**Update 2:**
I strongly recommend utilizing [`java.util.concurrent.Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) for executing fire-and-forget tasks.

Example:

```
Executors
    .newSingleThreadExecutor()
    .submit(Example::someMethod);
```

See more:  [`Platform.runLater` and `Task` in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-in-javafx), [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Answer (score 7):

In Java 8 if there is no parameters required you can use:

```
new Thread(MyClass::doWork).start();
```

Or in case of parameters:

```
new Thread(() -> doWork(someParam))
```

Comment: That's relative. The parameters are just hidden and it depends on the input parameters of the interface. When you write `new Thread(MyClass::doWork).start();` you could also write `new Thread(() ->doWork())` For Runabble has no input parameters. But if you require input from a variable that it's outside the closure, than yes, you can do the second way.