# Is there a way to hide a stage after a speficied time?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way to hide a stage after a specified time was passed like a few seconds or minutes ?

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-javafx

Comment: I think that `Platform.runLater()` will be useless here cause I'm working with only main thread ?. Maybe I should work on animations, like : it will work with a timeline and will do nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution with a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html):

```
final Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(new Scene(new Label("Hello")));
stage.show();
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10),
    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            stage.hide();
        }
    }));
timeline.play();
```