# Call ChoiceBox image click

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to create ChoiceBox which I want to call when I press the image below. Is there any to call ChoiceBox menu when I click on the image?

```
ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox();
        cb.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "New Document", "Open ",
            new Separator(), "Save", "Save as")
        );
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can initially put the ChoiceBox in your pane and set the visibility as `false`

```
cb.setVisible(false);
```

Later, when you click on the image, you can set the visibility as true !

```
image.setOnAction(new EventHandler<>{
    put void onAction()
    {
       cb.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

**Note** : I just typed the code, so not sure whether it will *compile* or not ! Just wanted to give you an idea !

Comment: For some unknown reason then I run this code insight a Task it's not working.

Comment: Task is a worker thread, all your javafx controls related changes must me done in javafx thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-javafx go through this !