# JavaFX - Control and Concurrency

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a sample Hello World JavaFx. I am using Eclipse and eFxclipse plugin. My Eclipse is kepler which is Eclipse 4.3.2 version and Java servion is Jdk1.7-045.

What I try to add is very little concurrency codes, I just want to update button text in the example. Could this backend task interact with upfront UI control, for example button, scene? If not, how could I make tailored backend task, then interact with UI control?

Thanks in advance

```
package com.juhani.fx.exer;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class HelloWorld extends Application{

    private static final short COREPOOLSIZE=2;
    private static final short MAXIMUMPOOLSIZE=2; 
    private static final int WORKQUEUECAPACITY=100;
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(
            HelloWorld.class.getName());

    private ExecutorService executors = new             ThreadPoolExecutor(COREPOOLSIZE,MAXIMUMPOOLSIZE,20,TimeUnit.MINUTES,new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(WORKQUEUECAPACITY));



    public static void main(String[] args) {
       LogMessage logMessage = new LogMessage("BEGIN",1.0,1,"HELLOWORLD");
       log.trace(logMessage.toString());
       launch(args);        

   }

   @Override
   public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException {
      primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
      final Button btn = new Button();
      btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
      btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
          @Override
          public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
         }
       });

      final StackPane root = new StackPane();
      root.getChildren().add(btn);
      final Scene scene= new Scene(root,300,250);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();

      Task<Boolean> task = new Task<Boolean>() {
         @Override 
         public Boolean call() {    
            for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
               btn.setText("First row\nSecond row "+i);
               primaryStage.show();
               try {
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  log.error(new LogMessage("entering interruption",1.0,2,"exception").toString());                       
               }
            }
            return new Boolean(true);               
          }        
       };           
       executors.submit(task);      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This answer specially talks about the use of Platform.runLater. If you are using Task, you are better off updating the UI using the method it provides as stated in 
[kleopatra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24991703/1759128).*

---

For updating the UI, you have to be on the Javafx thread.

Once you are on any other thread, use [`Platform.runLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to update those data back to Javafx UI. A working example can be found below

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    private static final short COREPOOLSIZE = 2;
    private static final short MAXIMUMPOOLSIZE = 2; 
    private static final int WORKQUEUECAPACITY = 100;

    private ExecutorService executors = new 
       ThreadPoolExecutor(COREPOOLSIZE, MAXIMUMPOOLSIZE, 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                          new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(WORKQUEUECAPACITY));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);        
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        final Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Task<Boolean> task = new Task<Boolean>() {
            @Override 
            public Boolean call() {    
                final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
                for( ; i.get() < 20; i.incrementAndGet()) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            btn.setText("First row\nSecond row " + i);                      
                        }
                    });

                try {
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
            return Boolean.valueOf(true);               
          }        
       };           
       executors.submit(task);      
    }   
}
```

For more information you can go through the links provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23920527/1759128)

Comment: tehcnically correct - but suboptimal because you aren't using Task's features ...

Comment: I see ! I always wanted to ask this, do you think that using the task's update feature makes a huge difference in the performance, inplace of using Platform.runlater ??

Comment: I thought `Platform.runLater` would be slow as it updates **at some unspecified time in the future**

Comment: .. as do the updateXX methods :-) Anyway, _thinking_ doesn't help when it comes to suspected performance issues, the only way to find out is _measuring_

Answer (score 2):

A Task is designed to interact with the ui on the fx-application thread, to take advantage of that support you should *use* it as designed :-)

As a general rule, you *must not* access ui in the call method [*] of the Task. Instead, update one of its properties (message, progress ...) and bind that property to your ui. Sample code:

```
Task<Boolean> taskWithBinding = new Task<Boolean>() {
    @Override 
    public Boolean call() {    
        final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        for( ; i.get() < 20; i.incrementAndGet()) {
            updateMessage("First row\nSecond row " + i);                      
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return Boolean.FALSE;
            }
        }
        return Boolean.TRUE;               
    }        
};           
btn.textProperty().bind(taskWithBinding.messageProperty());
```

[*] The one exception is outlined (wrap the access into an runLater) in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24984261/203657). Doing so is technically correct - but then you are by-passing a Task's abilities and could use an arbitrary Runnable ...