# IndexOutOfBoundsException while updating a ListView in JavaFX

Tags: listview, javafx, indexoutofboundsexception

I got a problem with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while I want to update a `ListView` in JavaFX.

#### What I need to do

I have a `ListView` with elements that correspond to a small simulation. With a click on one list-element the graphical simulation updates based on the click a element of the `ListView`. Afterwards the `ListView` needs a update and other elements will be shown. That means all old elements will be removed and only the new ones will be shown.

#### My code looks like that:

```
public void init() {
    // simCont.initSimulation() returns ArrayList
    ObservableList<Default> obsDefaultList = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList(simCont.initSimulation());
    listTest.getItems().addAll(obsDefaultList);
    listTest.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
            .addListener(new ChangeListener<Default>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(
                        ObservableValue<? extends Default> observable,
                        Default oldValue, Default newValue) {
                    updateList(newValue);
                }
            });
}

private void updateList(Default chosen) {
    ObservableList<Default> list = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList(simCont.doSimulationStep(chosen.getId()));
    listTest.getItems().clear();
    listTest.getItems().addAll(list);
}
```

At first there are two elements shown. When I click on one of them the `ListView` updates but I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:136)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:242)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$174(ListViewBehavior.java:258)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior$$Lambda$145/442103778.onChanged(Unknown Source)
at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:75)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:331)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:242)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:206)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:132)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at de.hhn.unitylab.controller.SimulationController.doSimulationStep(SimulationController.java:65)
at de.hhn.unitylab.ui.SimulatorViewController.updateList(SimulatorViewController.java:107)
at de.hhn.unitylab.ui.SimulatorViewController.access$0(SimulatorViewController.java:105)
at de.hhn.unitylab.ui.SimulatorViewController$1.changed(SimulatorViewController.java:94)
at de.hhn.unitylab.ui.SimulatorViewController$1.changed(SimulatorViewController.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$34(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase$$Lambda$127/2138925075.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:357)
at javafx.scene.control.ListView.lambda$new$156(ListView.java:374)
at javafx.scene.control.ListView$$Lambda$126/1092624378.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
at javafx.scene.Node$FocusedProperty.notifyListeners(Node.java:7526)
at javafx.scene.Scene$13.invalidated(Scene.java:2046)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:145)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.setFocusOwner(Scene.java:3891)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.requestFocus(Scene.java:3938)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3877)
at javafx.scene.Scene.requestFocus(Scene.java:2010)
at javafx.scene.Node.requestFocus(Node.java:7687)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.mousePressed(ListViewBehavior.java:360)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Debugging was confusing because I found no reason for the exception.
I searched the web but found nothing that worked for me. Hopefully somebody can help me with that issue.

Comment: The most probable reason for this is you performing a `listTest.getItems().clear();` on the data of your listView. You should handle such situations performing a `null check` inside your listeners

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ItachiUchiha. Unfortunately the null-check doesn't solve the problem. I checked it in the called method and listeners.

Comment: The stackTrace shows the error to be on line 65 of `doSimulationStep()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Bit late, but since you are still getting the exceptions, here's my two cents. I was getting the same error and here's what worked for me.

You can't update UI elements from a non-main thread. One way to do this is make a Runnable and schedule it on the main thread by runLater.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
//put your code here
}});
```

Comment: This approach removed an exception of the same type from my TableView application. For people that are less familiar with java, I would recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-javafx for a more detailed example.

Comment: I had similar issue, got fixed with @Stormbringer suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put the observalble list outside of a method (just like a normal field)

```
ObservableList<Default> listData = FXCollections.observableArrayList()

public void initialize(Url url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    listData.addAll(myService.getFoo);
    listTest.setItems(listData);

    //You could use lambdas here if you use Java8
    listTest.getSelectionModel.selectedItemProperty()
        .addListener(new ChangeListener<Default>(){

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Default> observable,
                        Default oldValue, Default newValue) {
                    //Update the graphical simulations somewhere here
                    listData.clear();
                    listData.add(new Default(..)); //Add new values to list
                }
        });
}
```

If you bind the list to a observable list objects, the table changes whenever the observable list (here `listData`). What you did wrong create a new observable list every time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've changed my code now according, but the exception is still thrown. I think it's a problem with the SelectionModel. When I simply add one element to the list, the code works fine. But if I remove anything from it, the exception is thorwn.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: Could you provide more code. e.g. the changed, doSimulationSet and access method and the line numbers resp. code on lines 65, 107 and 94 in Class SimulatorViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem while using a `ComboBox` and trying to update the backing `observablelist`.

I fixed it by changing the `ComboBox` to a `ChoiceBox` and now I don't get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` anymore.

Did you try using other containers?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in the similar situation of this answer:[JavaFX ComboBox change value causes IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370394/javafx-combobox-change-value-causes-indexoutofboundsexception)

try

```
Platform.runLater(() -> updateList(newValue) )
```

instead of `updateList(newValue)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue occured when I had ScenicView opened beside my JavaFX application. Closing it solved the problem.