# Debugging charm projects in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans-8, javafxports, gluon

I'm trying to debug a charm project. I've set break points in the code, but each time execution reaches a break point, Netbeans freezes and I'm obliged to forcefully close it.
For what it's worth, I'm using Ubuntu 15.04

[Edit 1]

Here's an image of a set break point

[image]

I am getting an exception: 
`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`
that doesn't point to any line in my code, so I want to debug and get what is causing the problem. Immediately the code gets to line 106, everything freezes.

[Edit 2]

Ok here's most of the controller code.

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        departmentList.setPlaceholder(new Label("Oops!! EMPTY!!!"));

        /*
         Populate SideMenu
         */
        ObservableList<Label> schools = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ListView<Label> schoolList = new ListView<>(schools);
        for (School school : schoolsList) {
            schools.add(new Label(school.getName(), MaterialDesignIcon.ACCOUNT_BALANCE.graphic()));
        }
        /*
         Add Listeners to side Menu ListView
         */
        schoolList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (ObservableValue<? extends Label> observable, Label oldValue, Label newValue) -> {
                    selectedSchool = parser.findSchool(newValue.getText());
                    loadDepartments();
                    MobileApplication.getInstance().hideLayer("Side Menu");

                });

        /*
         Add Listener to departments ListView
         */
        departmentList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (ObservableValue<? extends Label> observable, Label oldValue, Label newValue) -> {

                    if (newValue == null) {//Got fired by clearing the Observable list
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println(newValue);
                    facDept[1] = newValue.getText();
                    /*
                     Reset before leaving; *to be removed and tried on mobile
                     */
                    loadDepartments();
                    MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(SEMESTER_VIEW);
                });
        borderPane.setCenter(schoolList);
        center.getChildren().add(departmentList);
    }

    @FXML
    private void showLayer(ActionEvent event) {
        MobileApplication.getInstance().showLayer("Side Menu");
    }
```

I set a break point in the showLayer method(MobileApplication...), and debugging works. I set another one the line `selectedSchool = parser.findSchool(newValue.getText());`, but here debugging freezes. Note that the exception doesn't occur here.

Comment: Debugging works fine for me on a Charm project, with NetBeans on my Mac. I can't test on Linux. How do you launch debugging?

Comment: I launch debugging with the debug button next to the run button or a right click on the project and select debug. Actually its not only Netbeans that freezes. The OS freezes too, I can move the mouse but can't click. I force quit the running program using the keyboard.

Comment: Can you debug any other JavaFX project? And JavaFXPorts project (without Charm dependencies)? Do you set any breakpoint?

Comment: Yes; I can debug both JavaFX and simple JavaFXPorts projects. Netbeans doesn't freeze at the breakpoints.

Comment: It's hard to tell if you don't show where it gets stuck. I've tested debugging Charm with no problem at all. Can you show some code were you set the breakpoint?

Comment: I've edited the question to show the break point.

Comment: Once you have an exception, I'm not sure how the debugger will react. I suggest you use some try-catch first, to isolate the exception.

Comment: @JoséPereda I've solved the IndexOutOfBoundsException  problem using the solution from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27623202/4194406) but still not solved the debugging problem. I tried debugging the FiftyStates sample and encountered the same problem.