# How to make JavaFX thread-safe with Platform.runLater

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx

I'm making a JavaFX application in which I read a problem and generate a solution when the start button is pressed. The problem is that when I click the start button, the GUI hangs. I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-javafx) which suggests to wrap the thread-safe method in Platform.Runlater.

Now when the button is clicked, the method doBtnStartPressed() in my controller is called. This method only contains the call to the showSolution() method. Then I wrapped the content of this method in the Platform.runLater as follows:

```
private void showSolution() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           // solve problem
           // draw solution on panes (rectangles which represent time windows)
        }
    });
}
```

This however doesn't work.

Comment: The post you quote says (correctly) to "Use `PlatForm.RunLater` for quick and simple operations and `Task` for complex and big operations". You will need the concurrency framework (the `Task` and maybe more). See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) for an introduction.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried to wrap the content of the showSolution() method in a Task after which I call new Thread(task).start(); This however doesn't throw any exceptions but nothing is drawn on the pane. I'm sure that the task is being started.

Answer (score 1):

you can find a general overview of background tasks in JavaFX and how handle them here: http://www.guigarage.com/2014/10/datafx-8-released/ (scroll to the headline "ProgressChain").

In addition I mentioned this topic in my "JavaFX Enterprise" talk at JavaOne this year. You can find the slides here: http://de.slideshare.net/HendrikEbbers/javafx-enterprise-javaone-2014?related=1

A general discussion about Concurrency in JavaFX and UI Toolkits can be found here:

- Part 1: http://www.guigarage.com/2015/01/concurrency-ui-toolkits-part-1/
- Part 2: http://www.guigarage.com/2015/02/concurrency-ui-toolkits-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve the long running operation outside runLater and **also** construct the SceneGraph elements there (without actually attaching them to the parent) and then in one simply call add them to your real scene inside the runLater call.