# How to perform a longer running task requiring some GUI operations asynchronously in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

We have a set of scenes for which the intent is to - at a certain point after it is "safe" to do so - save them to image files. "Safe" here means "after some backend work done and also after the scenes are fully painted/rendered."

The single-threaded nature of the FxApplication thread needs to be taken into account : all gui related work needs to happen on the FxApplication thread. So then it is not clear to me how to do arbitrary gui-related operations that require access to the Graphics Context.

- the `javafx.application.Platform.runLater(runnable)` is intended for short-lived operations. In fact that is how we launch the separate scenes: one scene for each invocation of `runLater`. That works fine.
- the `Task` which is specifically intended for longer running operations. But ***how should the Task interoperate with the FxApplication thread?***  There does not seems to be any "queueing mechanism" for the Task to put work *back* into the FxApplication eventing loop.

  We should likely not attempt to perform GUI related ops from the Task - that would violate the FxApplication thread's responsibilities -and lead to race conditions.

Note the following question [Platform.runLater and Task in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-javafx) does not address this case because the GUI operation shown:

```
           bar.setProgress(counter/1000000.0);
```

is a "builtin". We need to do *arbitrary* gui operations.

..

So an outline  of how to properly sequence the work would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like: [Render 300 charts off screen and save them to files in JavaFX.](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5072743)

Comment: I did /have looked closely at that - and it influenced the approach in my answer.  I will add the link to the answer.  I had a separate issue that the rendering is still not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909297/getting-black-image-when-saving-a-javafx-snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach is working AFA running GUI operations in the "background" (there is only one GUI thread - so 'background' tasks for GUI operations is a relative term..)

**update** credit to @jewelsea for a significant chunk of the approach https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5072743   "Render 300 charts off screen and save them to files in JavaFX."

- Launch a block of code in `Platform.runLater`
- In that block of code launch a `Task`
- In the Task:

  - Do the off-thread backend non-gui work
  - When completed with the non-gui work:
  - launch a `Platform.runLater` that includes:
  - the GUI code you want to run *after* the backend operations were completed.

This approach is working: I can see the windows launched, then backend operations happening while the GUI is still responsive: and then eventually - once the backend operations are completed - the additional GUI operations are then performed.