# Wait() & Sleep() Not Working As Thought

Tags: multithreading, javafx-8, wait, sleep

Using JavaFX 8.0 and JRE 1.8.0 u45 in IntelliJ, I created a basic pixel editor app.  I have two windows(stages).  One is a 32x128 matrix of `Circle` Objects placed in a `Grid Pane` and the other, a Tools widow; I have one `Controller.java`.  Using the mouse, the Tools window provides tools to draw lines, rectangles, etc. and a menu for Setup, Files and Playlists.  The Files menu presents the user with Open, SaveAs and Delete.  To view a saved pixel art file, the user clicks Open and via the `JFileChooser`, the selected file is opened and each Circle’s assigned color is displayed using the following method:

```
public static void openFile( String pathName) throws IOException {

    path = Paths.get(pathName);
    pixelByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);

    int cnt = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {

            String hexRGB = String.format("#%02X%02X%02X",
                    pixelByteArray[cnt++],                  //red
                    pixelByteArray[cnt++],                  //green
                    pixelByteArray[cnt++]);                 //blue

            Color color = Color.valueOf(hexRGB);

            pixelArray[r][c].setFill(color);
        }
    }
    String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
    window.setTitle(MessageFormat.format("Pixel Array {0} x {1}    File:  {2}", Integer.toString(row), Integer.toString(col), fileName));

} // openFile
```

The Circle’s color is updated with for loops using setFill(color).

Next I created a class to test a basic slide show.  I would use `JFileChooser` to select multiple files, put them in an `ArrayList<file>` and use the `openFile(pathname)` in a `for` loop to display each, pausing 5 secs between each `openFile(pathname)` as shown below:

public class PlayPlaylist {

```
public static void playPlaylist() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:\\ProgramData\\L1 Art Files\\"));
    fileChooser.setTitle("Play One or More Pixel Art Files");
    java.util.List<File> selectedFiles = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(null);

   for (File selectedFile : selectedFiles) {
       openFile(selectedFile.getPath());
       sleep(5000);
   }
} //Method playPlaylist()
```

I first used `wait(5000)` but couldn’t compile because I have a static method, which I need.  The `wait()` method won’t run in a static method.  I then tried `sleep(5000)` which compiles but to my confusion only the last file in the `ArrayList<file>` will be displayed.  All the pixel art files will display the `setTitle()` correctly and pause for about 5 secs but the Circle’s will not change to the assigned color except for the last file, after the 5 secs have passed. The `for` loop, `setFill(color)` process in `openFile()` seems to be paused even though the `setTitle()` is executed correctly, which is after the `setFill(color)` process?

I’m new to Java and JavaFX and have never created any threads directly in this program or any other but researching possible problems implies the problem may be related to threads.

Is there a classic fix to this problem?  Thanks for any help

After studying the references and suggested solutions below, I am unable to fix the problem.  I tried two code changes.  The first was to the `for loop` code above:

```
for (File selectedFile : selectedFiles) {
       Platform.runLater(() -> {
           try {
               openFile(selectedFile.getPath());
               try {
                   sleep(5000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
```

The second change was to the openFile(pathname) above:

```
final int finalR = r;
final int finalC = c;
Platform.runLater(() -> pixelArray[finalR][finalC].setFill(color));
```

I get the same results as described above with only the last file being displayed.  If I simply select one file in the `Arraylist<File>` it will display, i.e.:

```
if (selectedFiles != null) {
        File playFile = selectedFiles.get(0);
        openFile(playFile.getPath());
        System.out.println("\n File 1 = " + playFile.getPath());
 }
```

Now if I add `Sleep(5000)`:

```
if (selectedFiles != null) {
        File playFile = selectedFiles.get(0);
        openFile(playFile.getPath());
        System.out.println("\n File 1 = " + playFile.getPath());
        sleep(5000);
    }
```

It will display the pixel art file after 5 secs.  What I don't understand is why it appears to "skip" over the `pixelArray[r][c].setFill(color));` which sets all the Circle's to the saved colors but does execute the following and last statement in the `openFile(pathname)` which is `setTitle(...)`?  It's like `sleep(5000)` blocks the `pixelArray[r][c].setFill(color));`but nothing else?

Why can I `openFile(pathname)` for just one file with proper results but not two or more in sequence?

I also have the two UI windows posted on the web at: [Virtual Art](https://virtualartsite.wordpress.com/). I think the pixel art shown in the Pixel Array window clarifies the goal of creating a user-defined slide show.

***This question was answered elegantly by jewelsea at:

How to avoid Thread.sleep() in a for loop from interrupting the UI Thread?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX periodic background task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task)

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems here, your understanding of `wait()`, and a GUI multithreading issue.

About the GUI multithreading...  You will find more informations here about `Platform.runLater(...)`:

[Platform.runLater and Task in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-javafx)

Now about `Wait`... It will pause your Thread until a `Notify` event is received through its monitor. To be able to call notify() you need to synchronize on the same object (the monitor).

```
synchronized (someObject) {
    someObject.wait();
}

/* different thread / object */
synchronized (someObject) {
    someObject.notify();
}
```

If you want to use `Wait`, you will need another Thread (a `Timer`?), to wakeup/notify you. `Sleep` should work fine in your case, as long as you use `Platform.runlater(...)`

Comment: There is no need to use these low-level constructs (which are tricky to get right, especially for a beginner) for something like this. Just use the provided classes in the JavaFX API. The question is essentially [already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task)

Comment: True, but it's important for a beginner to understand what is the UI Thread. I don't think @sgroen did.

Comment: Maybe. But you only really need that when you are creating your own thread, and the OP is not at that level of expertise yet (still struggling to understand when it is appropriate to use `static`, for example). I provided another explanation of the FX Application Thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests/30250308#30250308), which I think is more complete (though your opinion may of course differ).

Comment: This question was answered elegantly by jewelsea at:

How to avoid Thread.sleep() in a for loop from interrupting the UI Thread?