# How to update fxml Label from a background worker?

Tags: java, javafx, backgroundworker, fxml

I have a label in my fxml file:

```
<Label fx:id="labelA"/>
```

I want to update this in the controller during a background worker is executing. I have tried to do something like this:

```
public class FXHelloCVController
{
    @FXML
    private Label labelA;
    @FXML
    protected void startMatching(ActionEvent event)
    {   
        SwingWorker<Boolean, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Boolean, String>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception
            {

                for(int y=0; y<*something*; y++){
                    if(n.get(y)!=null){
                        ...
                        publish(n.get(y).name);
                        ...
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                String n = chunks.get(chunks.size()-1);
                labelA.setText(n);
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
        return;
    }
```

But when the function "labelA.setText(n)" is called, it appears the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Gianna don't mix Swing with JavaFX instead of this java has something very nice which is Service and Worker classes have a look here:http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm (it is not too easy to learn at once but once you do is really cool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platform.runLater: If you need to update a GUI component from a non-GUI thread, you can use that to put your update in a queue and it will be handle by the GUI thread as soon as possible.

```
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // update an FXML node (e.g. label)
        }
    });
```

Source: [Platform.runLater and Task in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-in-javafx)

But you're using Swing and JavaFX, which isn't usually.

Answer (score 1):

A SwingWorker is for Swing and not for JavaFX. Have a look at the documentation for the corresponding JavaFX concurrency mechanisms.