# JavaFX Concurrency: Can I run an objects method in a task?

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

If I have a class with methods:

```
class Car{
    private String engineRPM;

    public Car(){}

    public String idleEngine(){
        if (engineOn()){
            engineRPM = getEngineRPM();
        }
        return engineRPM;
    }
}
```

**How do I run the method in a task on a background thread in Main and then take its returned value and update the GUI?**

```
public class Main extends Application {

Car myCar;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/entry.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    this.mainController = (SystemMessage) loader.getController();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Car");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();

    //perform background task of class method here
    myCar = new Car();
    myCar.startEngine();
    String RPM = myCar.engineIdle(); //
    this.mainController.postMessage(RPM);

}
```

Comment: you can use the Platform.runLater(Runnable...) to do it. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-in-javafx

Comment: @Serge `Platform.runLater(...)` runs something on the FX Application Thread, not on a background thread. So I guess you mean by this the UI update at the end should use `Platform.runLater(...)`. That is not clear from the comment.

Comment: @James_D yes, this is what i meant. Sorry for the truncated note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is

- Create a `Task` whose `call()` method does whatever you need to do in the background thread
- If you have something to execute on the FX Application Thread when the task finishes, use the `onSucceeded` handler, which is invoked (on the FX Application Thread) after the `call()` method completes
- When the `call()` method finishes, whatever is returned from it is set as the task's `value`, so you can call `getValue()` to see what was returned
- Create a thread from the task, and call `start()` to execute it

So in your case, this just looks like

```
public class Main extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/entry.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        SystemMessage mainController = loader.getController();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Car");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

        Task<String> carTask = new Task<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                Car myCar = new Car();
                myCar.startEngine();
                return myCar.engineIdle();
            }
        };
        carTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> mainController.postMessage(carTask.getValue()));
        new Thread(carTask).start();

    }

}
```

See the [documentation for `Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html): it has plenty of examples.

Comment: This is starting to click!!! Thank you. One more question. If I want to run several methods inside the task could I update the GUI with the response of each one with the `postMessage` method I have? or do I need to figure out how to use `updateMessage()`

Comment: @silversunhunter If there is just one `String` you are changing, you can call `updateMessage()`, and then bind your UI control to the task's message, or register a listener with the task's `messageProperty()`. More generally, you can perform progressive UI updates by putting the calls that update the UI in your `call()` method, each one wrapped in `Platform.runLater()`. Again, see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), e.g. the example "A Task Which Modifies The Scene Graph".