# JavaFX Multithreading Concept

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, server, client

Before I start: I'm a newbee in JavaFX and with this project i want to learn how to use this library properly.

The situation is the following: i have a server-client application. The server sends the client a list of the active users on the server. Now i want to list the active users in the UI. I wanted to do that with buttons in  FlowPane. The problem is that my client is in an external thread, so not in the application-thread. But because of the fact that the client gets the list on users, I tried to update the button-list directly from the client-thread.

```
            if(data.getObject() instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
                ArrayList<User> activeUsers = (ArrayList<User>) data.getObject();
                controller.setActiveUsers(activeUsers);
            }
```

The method in my controller does the following:

```
public void setActiveUsers(ArrayList<User> activeUsers) {
    for(User user:activeUsers) {
        fpOnlineUsers.getChildren().add(new Button(user.getName()));
    }
}
```

The Exception i get is the following:`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3`

I have two questions:

1. How can i fix this?
2. Why blocks JavaFX changed made from threads other than the application-thread?

Please apologize any language mistakes, I'm not a native speaker :)

Comment: You can fix this by using [Platform#runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) to update your `FlowPane`. You have to do this in the JavaFX aplication thread because [it is not thread safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) like Swing.

Comment: @Pagbo Swing is [not thread safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) either (some parts are, as stated in the link, but they are specially documented as such).

Comment: @Slaw that 's what I said, or at least I wanted to say (I personnally consider Swing is not thread safe at all).

Comment: @Pagbo Oops, sorry. When I read "_like Swing_" I interpreted it as "_in contrast to Swing_" and not as "_similar to Swing_".

Comment: @Slaw I noticed after your first comment it was a little confusing. Sorry for the misunderstanding and thanks to enlighten it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to make any JavaFX object related calls on the Application Thread. To do this from your client Thread use the `Application.runlater(Runnable)` function.

Your code should look something like this:

```
public void setActiveUsers(ArrayList<User> activeUsers) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            for(User user:activeUsers) {
                fpOnlineUsers.getChildren().add(new Button(user.getName()));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Reference: 
[Platform.runLater and Task in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-in-javafx)