# Cannot perform a while loop in a custom Thread when pressing a ToggleButton twice (works only the first time)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

The way my program works, I have a method being called when the button is pressed. Then, the idea is that I have a new thread that has a while loop that calls another method every specified amount of time until the togglebutton is pressed again. How would I program such a thing? I tried Thread.wait() but it causes issues with the GUI updating.

Solved. Thank you!

Comment: If your periodic task is simple and quick then use the [animation API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) (e.g. [JavaFX periodic background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task)). Otherwise, if it's a periodic _background_ task, see [`ScheduledService`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to save the `Thread` object to a global variable and stop it when the `toggleButton` is pressed again.

Using the `wait` method on the thread will not work, because `wait` does not work like you expect it (see [Object.wait() in javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()))

The second problem (IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread) is probably caused by the method `performAction(ActionEvent)` because it tries to change things in the GUI, which is not allowed from another thread than the application thread. To avoid this you can use `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` (see [javadock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-in-javafx))

A solution could look like this:

```
private Thread thread;

//call this method every time the toggle button is pressed
private void play(final ActionEvent ae) {
    if (thread == null) {
        //start in a new thread
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {//better add a runnable to the new Thread than overwriting the run method of Thread
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {//run until the thread is interrupted
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(speed);
                        //run this in platform to avoid the IllegalStateException that no fx thread is used
                        Plaform.runLater(() -> performAction(ae));
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                        //set the interrupted flag again (was unset when exception was caught)
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
    else {
        //stop the current thread
        thread.interrupt();
        thread = null;
    }
}
```